# How can I use class_getProperty in iPad?(Not simulator)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm using `class_getProperty()` in my iPad app. I tried `#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>`, which works on iPad simulator.

But when I try to run it on my iPad, Xcode says:

> objc/objc-runtime.h: No such file or directory

and

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'class_getProperty'.

Comment: When you try to *run* it? You mean try to *build* it, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that there are differences between the simulator and the device. The simulator does not run the exact same SDK as the device. The lower layers are from the Mac SDK actually, which makes sense since it's executed on a mac.

However, it seems there is a fix for your specific problem. You should definitely try the fix Jeff Lamarche describes in this post: [Device vs. Simulator](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/device-vs-simulator.html)

Replace

```
#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>
```

By

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>
```

Then to get rid of the warning, you add these two lines in the header file of the involved class :

```
#if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
- (NSString *)className;
+ (NSString *)className;
#endif
```

And then in the implementation file :

```
#if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE)
- (NSString *)className {
 return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:class_getName([self class])];
}
+ (NSString *)className {
 return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:class_getName(self)];
}
#endif
```

Comment: I appreciate you for very quick answer!
And it successfully worked!

I'll be careful for differences between the simulator and the device from now.

Comment: Great ! If the answer suits, maybe you can mark it as accepted so other people who encounter this issue may instantly see this fix is correct ?